# MySQL select distinct order by id

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by, distinct

I have a table like the following:

```
id category
1  A
2  A
3  B
4  B
5  C
6  C
```

If I want to select the top 2 distinct categories ordered by id descending, what's the right query in mysql? I tried `select distinct category from table order by id desc limit 2` but that gave me the following result:

```
category
C
C
```

instead of

```
category
C
B
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By top 2, you seem to mean the ones at the end of the list.  Try this:

```
select category
from t
group by category
order by max(id) desc
limit 2
```

If you mean the ones with the most rows.

Try this:

```
select category
from t
group by category
order by count(*) desc
limit 2
```

You can also include the `count(*)` in the select list to see what the counts are.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the ones with the most rows. I just want 2 results ordered by id descending.

Comment: @user366810 . . . I know, I revised the answer.

Comment: That works. Thanks. I should have just asked you an hour ago :)

Comment: This answer was pretty constructive for me. Solved my problem! Thanks:)